# the with plural

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

We know that the definite article can often be used with things that are "expected to be" in the context (even when they haven't been mentioned).

> e.g. When I wake up I go to the kitchen

("the kitchen" hasn't been mentioned in the previous context but it's expected that a normal person would have a kitchen in the place where they live) or

> I went to a restaurant last night and I had to call **the chef** because
> **the food** was tasteless

("the chef is expected to be in a restaurant as well as "the food").
Despite working pretty well with singular nouns, I've noticed that this logic often doesn't apply to nouns in plural. Thus, I've come up with some examples, Could you please provide all possible asnwers for each example (e.g. ex.1 - the/zero article are possible, ex.2: only the is possible etc.)

> She got mad at me yesterday. She walked into the kitchen and started
> breaking (the?) **plates**
>
> She got mad at me yesterday. She walked into the living room and
> started breaking (the?) **furniture**
>
> I was at the library last night and a lot of people were using (the?)
> **computers** instead of reading (the?) **books**
>
> I run a medical clinic. In my clinic we pay (the?) **doctors** a lot
>
> (the?) **Inmates** in this prison are treated like animals
>
> in the MIT college (the?)**teachers** really care about (the?) **students**
>
> Google pays a lot to (the?) **employees** who perform well.
>
> (the?) **Education** I received in college didn't help my career

**ADDED:**

> I don't like this movie, but I like (the?) actors and special effects

(is it possible to use "zero article" before "actors" in this context?)

I hope you can help me, thank you for your time!

Comment: Lots of example sentences tends to attract long, unclear answers and nitpicks. Two examples of the same thing is the most you need. The others just make for more work for those answering.

Comment: I appreciate your advice and I agree with the first part (the one about nitpicks and unclear answers), However, since I am doing a research I'm trying to stick to the following principles:
1. the more data you analyze - the more precise your results are
2. any hypothesis or model needs numerous confirmations before we can consider it reliable
Hence, the multitude of similar examples

Comment: In English, you can't say: I wake up and go to kitchen. You could say: go to a kitchen, if there were several to choose from. If you have a plural noun, you don't need anything: Actors [general idea] can be very nice people. BUT: I like **the actors** [specific idea] in this movie.

Comment: @Lambie  Thanks! Is it possible to say "Actors in this movie are great", though? (without using "the")

Comment: Not to be formally grammatical. Maybe in instant messaging.

Comment: Thanks! Do you agree with other users that all of these examples are fine even with zero article? (except the last 2 about education and actors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your examples **except the one with "Education"** are correct with or without the definite article.

I'm not sure where you get the idea that there is a difference for plurals.

Added:

In the case of the singular, a definite article is used to differentiate between referring to a single instance of the thing in question or one of many (even  in the case where you might naturally expect only one - such as 'the owner').

In the case of plurals there are obviously many.

So:

- I spoke to the chef :: There was only one chef.
- I spoke to a chef :: There were several chef's and I spoke to one.
- I spoke to waiters :: Clearly, there were multiple waiters so you don't need to use an article, but you can, to imply how many you spoke to.

Note that there are exceptions: a teacher might say: "I went into school, today", because there is only one school that s/he would be going to.

**Edited in response to an error pointed out by Kate Bunting.**

Comment: I got this theory from analyzing the language.
I went to a restaurant and talked to the owner ("the owner " is expected, i cannot say "an owner")
I went to a restaurant and talked to the waiters ("the waiters" are expected but I can also say "waiters" with zero article) So the logic for "things that are expected" changes when I use nouns in plural, at least from what I can tell. And by the way, thank you for providing an answer!

Comment: I agree with @PRL75 except that I consider that the last one _does_ require _the_, and the one before doesn't (_its employees_ or _those employees_ would be better). In the other sentences, _the_ implies _the ones that are/were there_

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but article-less *started **breaking plates*** more strongly alludes to a "known, familiar" activity. Specifically, what Greek taverna waiters sometimes do after all the customers have finished eating (because they'd rather do folk dancing than the washing up! :)

Comment: @Mr. Past Progressive Sorry, I think I misinterpreted your question. I've expanded the answer.

Comment: You can say 'I went to a restaurant and talked to an owner' if, as many restaurants do, it has more than one owner. When I as a student I worked in one that had three owners, who each had an equal share in the business. It was called, by coincidence, 'Michael's Restaurant' but the three owners were called Jean-Paul, Richard, and Helen.

Comment: @KateBunting Can I ask you about another example? "We've got to hurry, In this city (the?) banks close at 5 p.m." Am I right to assume that both "zero" and "the" are natural here?

Comment: Both are acceptable; I would find _the banks_ more natural (the ones in this city).